# Return List from JPA query in Spring rest api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a list of objects which I would like to return in Spring rest API:

```
public Stream<PaymentTransactions> findListByReference_transaction_id(Integer id);
```

I tried this:

```
@GetMapping("/reference_transaction_id/{id}")
public Stream<Object> getByListReference_transaction_id(@PathVariable String id) {
    return transactionService
            .findListByReference_transaction_id(Integer.parseInt(id)).collect()
            .map(mapper::toDTO)
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok).orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());;
}
```

I have two issues which I need help to solve.

1. How I can return `ResponseEntity<List<PaymentTransactions>>` not Stream in order to read it as Arraylist in Angular.
2. For `orElseGet` I get error `The method orElseGet(() -> {}) is undefined for the type Stream<ResponseEntity<PaymentTransactionsDTO>>`

How I can solve these issues? Can you give me some advice, please?

Comment: You first have to collect to a list.

Comment: Can you paste official answer, how to do it please?

Comment: Use `collect`... Also you don't have to return a `List` from the `findListByReference_transaction_id` method just return a `Stream`. Bit strange to first create a list, transform it in a stream to goto a list again. Quite some overhead in there.

Comment: Ok, I changed the result from the SQL query to return a Stream. But how should I use collect?

Answer (score 0):

This would solve the Stream to List issue.

```
.map(mapper::toDTO).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

And your method return type can be changed to

```
ResponseEntity<?>
```

Comment: Thanks. How about the second question?

Comment: For the second question, you can use the `.orElse(ResponseEntity.ok().build())`